# Tuleap - project mail notification issue

Tags: tuleap

I have installed Tuleap and configured postfix mail setting in the server.

We have configured 4-5 projects in the tool. For each and every project, I have turned on the send notification option in the Task tracker. Tuleap sends a alert mail based on that configuration.

Everything was working fine ever since when the tool was installed, until last week, when I unchecked the send notification option for one of the projects and Tuleap kept sending alert mail for every status change in the artifact.

I need to stop that behavior on a project to project basic, as I want notifications to be sent only for selected projects.

Comment: What did you do to "uncheck[ed] the send notification option for one of the projects" ?

Comment: I have selected the Task Trackers, in that field usage section i have a assigned to option. When we edit that field, we have an option like select notifications to selected people, there i can uncheck[ed] any one of the projects based upon my need or requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your configuration (as described in your comment), the behaviour should be:

- The people assigned to the artifact should not receive the mail

But there are 2 general exceptions to that:

- If one is creator of the artifact or added a comment to the artifact, this one will always be notified
- If you add someone in a "CC" field (Open List), they will be notified.

Comment: I know that, what i really want is that when i uncheck the select notification option, the tool should not send mail to the assigned users. But the tool is sending mail to the users whoever is assigned.

Comment: Therefore it's a bug and should be reported here: https://tuleap.net/plugins/tracker/?tracker=140